# Is there any REST API to refresh specific table in a Power BI Dataset?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

[image: Like a refresh data menu in Power BI desktop.]

Like a refresh data menu in Power BI desktop. I have exported these datasets from SQL Server database by running stored procedure query.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly not.

The most specific API to refresh data is "Refresh Dataset In Group" but it will update the full dateset.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. Yeah, I'm aware of it but I want to know is there any way to refresh the table programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If your workspace is assigned to a Power BI Premium Capacity or Premium Per User you can use the [XMLA endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools?#dataset-refresh) programmatically to refresh just one table in a dataset.

Comment: Hi GregGalloway, thanks for your response. I'm not using Analysis Services. I'm using SQL Server for retrieving the data for the dataset. This solution seems for the Analysis Services Tabular model.

Comment: @Sanjay it uses the same XMLA protocol and tools as you would with Analysis Services but you are managing datasets on Power BI Premium. See the link I mentioned above. Are you on Power BI Premium? (Workspaces have a diamond icon)